# Please help me identify the set these LEGO parts are from

Tags: set-identification

They could definitely be from two separate sets. Any help would be appreciated!

[image: mini fig face out of plates and SHOP sign]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's an easy one:

[image]

It's part of the [Modular Buildings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Modular_Buildings) series in the LEGO Creator Expert line.
It's a series intended for the advanced builder, consisting of detailed buildings that click together to form a street.

Comment: You are the best!

Comment: (@AliceShah you can mark it as the Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post.)